# Why does the following code using Iterator next() and remove() throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator

I tested the `next()` and `remove()` methods of the `Iterator` interface. I got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

        Collections.addAll(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to close as duplicate as the answers here explain absolutely nothing about the exception.

Comment: @DenysSéguret you are right, I added more details to my answer to explain a little bit more

Comment: @NicolasFilotto *Now* you answer the question :)

Comment: @DenysSéguret this is ungrateful side of SO, if you take too much time to answer you will get less votes sometimes it is better to provide a quick and dirty answer first and then improve it

Comment: Or not answer at all and vote to close as duplicate, since they answer it already very well... I don't see the point in duplicating content.

Comment: @Tunaki You don't see the point, because it's about points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no problem with your usage of `Iterator`'s `next()` and `remove()`.

Your `ConcurrentModificationException` is caused by adding elements to the `List` after creating the `Iterator`.

You should add elements to the `List` before the `Iterator` is created.

Change:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
Collections.addAll(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

to:

```
Collections.addAll(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
```

and your loop will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You get this exception because you modify the sate of your `List` by adding elements after having created your iterator so when you call `next()` on your iterator, internally it checks if the underlying `List` has been modified and if so it raises a `ConcurrentModificationException` which is the case here.

Try to inverse the order as next:

```
Collections.addAll(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
```